# AutoCompleteExtender has wrong position, for webkit browsers, after scrolling down the page

Tags: asp.net, webkit, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an AutoCompleteExtender on my page which works fine but when I scroll down the page and use it, suggestions show up at wrong (vertical) position.
It happens with Safari & Chrome but not with IE &FF and so I thought it could be webkit's fault.
Heres the code:

```
<td>
      <div style="position: relative;">
           <asp:TextBox ID="DepartureAirportTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="DepartureAirport airport-textbox"
                            onblur="javascript:DepartureLostFocus();" onkeydown="javascript:DepartureChanged(event);"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Panel ID="DepartureAutocompleteDropDownPanel" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical"
                            CssClass="autocomplete-panel" Style="display: none;" />
            <AjaxControlToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="DepartureAirportAutoComplete" runat="server"
                            TargetControlID="DepartureAirportTextBox" CompletionSetCount="200" ServicePath="../WebServices/SecureService.asmx"
                            ServiceMethod="ListAirports" MinimumPrefixLength="3" BehaviorID="DepartureAirport"
                            CompletionListElementID="DepartureAutocompleteDropDownPanel" OnClientItemSelected="SelectDepartureAirport"
                            OnClientPopulating="ShowDepartureIcon" OnClientPopulated="HideDepartureIcon">
           </AjaxControlToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>               
     </div>
</td>
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338855/autocompleteextender-position-is-wrong-in-webkit) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991361/autocompleteextender-positioning-menu-incorrectly-when-scrolled) solutions on SO, but none worked.
How to fix it?

Update:
Even [the simplest example](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete_simple.ashx) from Microsoft has this problem. Add some `<p>` elements before and after the textbox & extender to create scrollable area and test it.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMovie" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <AjaxControlToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" TargetControlID="txtMovie"
            runat="server" UseContextKey="True" MinimumPrefixLength="2" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" />
```

Get code for `GetCompletionList` from above link. This issue is so easily reproducible.

Comment: I think that this must be made by the one that have made this autocomplete. I think the issue is the final render, the menu that drops is not inside a div with the text box and the css need fix also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a [solution on Asp.net forums](http://forums.asp.net/t/1252391.aspx/1?Positioning%20an%20autocompleteextender%20list%20in%20relation%20to%20its%20target%20control).

```
function resetPosition(object, args) {
    var tb = object._element;
    var tbposition = findPositionWithScrolling(tb);
    var xposition = tbposition[0];
    var yposition = tbposition[1] + 20; // 22 textbox height 
    var ex = object._completionListElement;
    if (ex)
        $common.setLocation(ex, new Sys.UI.Point(xposition, yposition));
}
function findPositionWithScrolling(oElement) {
    if (typeof (oElement.offsetParent) != 'undefined') {
        var originalElement = oElement;
        for (var posX = 0, posY = 0; oElement; oElement = oElement.offsetParent) {
            posX += oElement.offsetLeft;
            posY += oElement.offsetTop;
            if (oElement != originalElement && oElement != document.body && oElement != document.documentElement) {
                posX -= oElement.scrollLeft;
                posY -= oElement.scrollTop;
            }
        }
        return [posX, posY];
    } else {
        return [oElement.x, oElement.y];
    }
}
```

Call `resetPosition` on Extender's `OnClientShown` event

Comment: Still wondering what the $common is! Is it an instance of Sys.UI.DomElement class?